# Match character set and optional entity

Tags: php, regex

So i wanted to insert a word break character in every 5 character of a string using this code.

```
([^\s-]{5})([^\s-]{5})
```

Unfortunately it also breaks on entity characters (`&#xxx;`).
Can someone provide me an example that will not break the entity code?
The string that I want to break is from an xml so the actual entity are further escaped (`&amp;#xxx;`).

**Edit** code sample

```
preg_replace('/([^\s-]{5})([^\s-]{5})/', '$1&shy;$2', $subject)

Given the word "F&amp;#xe5;revejle"
Expect "F&amp;#xe5;&shy;revejle" as result
But it outputs "F&shy;5;revejle" instead
```

Comment: That's not code, that's just a regex which isn't doing much by itself. Can you show us the actual code you're using this regex with, and a sample string before and after? Especially what you'd like it to be after, not what you're getting now.

Comment: What about the named entities: `&amp;`, `&quot`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`?  And hexadecimal entities: `/&#x[A-Fa-f0-9]+;/`?  What if a numeric entity represents a hyphen or a whitespace character?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to split each word after five characters, unless they are already separated by hyphens, treating an entity as a single character, try this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/            # Start the match 
    (?:           # at one of the following positions:
     (?<=         # Either right after...
      [\s-]       # a space or dash
     )            # end of lookbehind
     |            # or...
     \G           # wherever the last match ended.
    )             # End of start condition.
    (             # Now match and capture the following:
     (?>          # Match the following in an atomic group:
      &amp;\#\w+; # an entity
      |           # or
      [^\s-]      # a non-space, non-dash character
     ){5}         # exactly 5 times.
    )             # End of capture
    (?=[^\s-])    # Assert that we\'re not at the end of a "word"/x', 
    '\1&shy;', $subject);
```

This changes

```
supercalifragilisticexpidon'tremember! 
alrea-dy se-parated 
count entity as one character&amp;#345;blahblah
F&amp;#xe5;revejle
```

into

```
super&shy;calif&shy;ragil&shy;istic&shy;expid&shy;on'tr&shy;ememb&shy;er! 
alrea-dy se-parat&shy;ed 
count entit&shy;y as one chara&shy;cter&amp;#345;&shy;blahb&shy;lah
F&amp;#xe5;rev&shy;ejle
```

Comment: Clever. Nice one! The only thing that bothers me *a little* is the use of `\b` - it isn't identical to the OP's definition of a word character (for example, it wouldn't add a dash in `a !!!!!? b`, if I understand correctly).

Comment: By the way, I did take a little shortcut; I'm not checking whether whatever follows `&amp;#` is actually a hex number.

Comment: Works ok on `F&amp;#xe5;revejle` but not with these "`&amp;#xd8;ster Hurup Strand" > "&.#xd8;.ster Hurup Stran.d"` and `"Danmark - B&amp;#xf8;ged Strand" > "Danma.rk - B&.;#xf8.;ged Stran.d"` (dot denotes shy)

Comment: correction
Works ok on `F&amp;#xe5;revejle` but not with these "`&amp;#xd8;ster Hurup Strand" > "&amp;.#xd8;.ster Hurup Stran.d"` and `"Danmark - B&amp;#xf8;ged Strand" > "Danma.rk - B&amp.;#xf8.;ged Stran.d"` (dot denotes shy)

Comment: Ah yes, the regex fails if the words containing entities are 5 characters or less. But it was easy to fix (I think): I just had to change the non-capturing group around the 5 characters into an atomic group, preventing the regex engine from backtracking and splitting up the entity. Please try it now.